# How to add clear option t qplaintextedit?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `qplaintextedit` that is loaded dynamically with text contents, with `QString`.

I want to add an option to the menu that appears when we right click on the qplaintextedit. How can I do it programmatically so that I am able to add my own menu item to the default menu item? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can sublcass `QPlainTextEdit` and reimplement the method `contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)`. Alternatively you can add an event filter to a `QPlainTextEdit` and catch the `QContextMenuEvent`.

In your implementation, you can call `QMenu *QPlainTextEdit::createStandardContextMenu(const QPoint &position)` to create the default menu of the text edit and than add your custom items to it.

Example (subclass):

```
void MyTextEdit::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QMenu* menu = createStandardContextMenu(event->pos());
    QAction* clearAction = menu->addAction("Clear");
    QAction* choosedAction = menu->exec(event->globalPos());
    //...
    delete menu;  
}
```

See:

- [Event handlers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-handlers)
- [Event filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)
- [QPlainTextEdit::contextMenuEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#contextMenuEvent)
- [QPlainTextEdit::createStandardContextMenu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#createStandardContextMenu-1)

Comment: I have made the qplaintextedit box using drag and drop.

Comment: Had i made the entire thing programmatically then your solution would be viable.

Comment: @Sumeet - by "drag and drop", do you mean using Qt Designer?  If so, you can use "Promoted widgets..." in Designer's context menu to turn your `QPlainTextEdit` into a `MyTextEdit`.  You still have to implement `MyTextEdit`, of course.

Comment: @TobySpeight If I do that, then it gives an error in the ui file, because it changes all the constructors.

Comment: @TobySpeight Hey it already has the delete option when i right click, but it is disable by default. Can I make it enabled by default.

Comment: @sumeet, did you specify the correct include file for your new class in the "Promoted widgets..." dialog?  If you got that wrong, then it won't compile - `moc` needs to be able to see the definition of your widget.

Comment: @Sumeet The default delete action in the menu is for delete the selected text. If no text is selected, the option is disabled

Comment: @Fabio Can I enable it somehow

Answer (score 0):

You have to reimplement the function : `void QPlainTextEdit::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)`

More details in the doc here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#contextMenuEvent

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to subclass QPlainTextEdit, nor to use an event filter.  You can do it all in the main widget of your application.  The following worked for me using Qt versions 4.7.4 and 4.8.5.

In the Designer:

You add a `QPlainTextEdit` widget whose name is "textbox".

In MainWindow.h:

```
// Auto generated from MainWindow.ui
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

private:
  /// The auto generated user interface.
  Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
  ...
}
```

In MainWindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget * pParent, Qt::WFlags flags )
  : QMainWindow( pParent, flags )
  , ui( )
{
    ui.textbox->setContextMenuPolicy( Qt::CustomContextMenu );
    connect( ui.textbox, SIGNAL( customContextMenuRequested( QPoint ) ),
      this, SLOT( onTextboxCustomContextMenuRequested( QPoint ) ) );
}

void MainWindow::onTextboxCustomContextMenuRequested( QPoint p )
{
  // Start with the standard menu.
  QMenu * pMenu = ui.textbox->createStandardContextMenu();
  QAction * pAction;

  // Clear.
  // Because QPlainTextEdit::clear() is a slot method, I can connect directly to it.
  pAction = new QAction( "Clear", this );
  connect( pAction, SIGNAL( triggered() ), ui.textbox, SLOT( clear() ) );
  pMenu->addAction( pAction );

  // Show the menu.
  QPoint q = ui.textbox->mapToGlobal( p );
  pMenu->exec( q );

  // The menu's ownership is transferred to me, so I must destroy it.
  delete pMenu;
}
```